# What if an fd is being closed while other function is blocking on it?

Tags: linux, pipe, posix, ipc, manual

According to the manual page of [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html):

```
If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will
block until data is available.  If a process attempts to write to a
full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has
been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete.  Nonblocking
I/O is possible by using the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation to enable the
O_NONBLOCK open file status flag.
```

I have such a question:

**Provided that a pipe buffer is empty;**

**A read is blocking on the pipe;**

**Now, if the write end is being closed, will the read be unblocked automatically?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `read` will be unblocked and return EOF (0).